# Does this question seem too subjective?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

The question [Apache Solr Geo Integration, Simple Geo, or Localsolr](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1114/apache-solr-geo-integration-simple-geo-or-localsolr) seems too subjective, as it asks "which one would you take for indexing locations and geo searches?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you primarily concerned with the form of the question, of the face that it will solicit opionions on which is best?

I honestly don't see a problem with it. You could re-ask the question in a "which of these is best" phrasing, and you are still going to get opinions (hopefully backed up by facts, and links).

Either way, I think there's the potential useful information to come out of the question, so I'd just leave it as is.

Comment: The [FAQ](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq) reports that questions where each answer is equally valid should be avoided; without any objective criteria, each answer should be valid, also because each module would better suit specific cases. The user didn't provided any information about his needs; at least, the question should be a CW, if it is acceptable.

Comment: I suppose my main point was that hopefully the responses will be backed by facts and links to back up the opinions expressed. Which, hopefully, will add more or less validity to the opinions expressed. I can also see your point though.. but would suggest we just keep an eye on it and see what comes out of it though.